# upload functionality is not working by using document.forms[0].submit(), its working when I gave it as type=submit

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="FileUpload" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Form Post Test</legend>

    <!-- <input   type="file" multiple="true" id="uploader2" name="uploadedfile" class="fileInput" data-dojo-attach-point="_fileInput" 
        dojoType="dojox.form.Uploader" label="Select Some Files"> 
        <input
        type="text" name="album" value="Summer Vacation" /> <input
        type="text" name="year" value="2011" /> 
        <input type="button" id="clear" label="Clear" value="clear"/>
        <input type="submit"
        label="Submit" value="submit1234" />
       <div id="files" dojoType="dojox.form.uploader.FileList"
        uploaderId="uploader1"></div>-->

    <input name="uploadedfile" multiple="true" type="file" id="uploader" data-dojo-type="dojox.form.Uploader" data-dojo-props='label:"Select Some Files"' />
    <input type="submit" label="Submit" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" />
    <div id="files" data-dojo-type="dojox.form.uploader.FileList" data-dojo-props='uploaderId:"uploader"'></div>
    <input type="submit" label="Submit" value="htmlsubmit">
    <input type="button" label="Submit" value="buttonsubmit" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();" />
```

In the above code, when I click on `htmlsubmit` button the selected file is uploading. But when I click on `buttonsubmit`, file is not getting uploaded.

I would like to know the difference between `type="submit"` and `type="button"` in case of file upload functionality

Comment: Your code only work to first input submit.
A form only permit have an input sumbit type, which is why the second does not. To resolve this, create a javascript function to submit the form, and clicking on any one of the input calls this function

Comment: I have done that but still Iam not able to get file data

Comment: what `label="Submit" ` do?

Comment: nothing to do with that, I hv removed label and tried, its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try change this:

```
<input  name="uploadedfile" multiple="true"  type="file" id="uploader"
    data-dojo-type="dojox.form.Uploader" data-dojo-props='label:"Select Some Files"' />        
    <input type="submit" label="Submit" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" />
    <div id="files" data-dojo-type="dojox.form.uploader.FileList"
        data-dojo-props='uploaderId:"uploader"'></div> 
<input type="submit" label="Submit" value="htmlsubmit" >
        <input type="button" label="Submit" value="buttonsubmit" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();"/>
```

to:

```
<input  name="uploadedfile" multiple="true"  type="file" id="uploader"
    data-dojo-type="dojox.form.Uploader" data-dojo-props='label:"Select Some Files"' />  
    <div id="files" data-dojo-type="dojox.form.uploader.FileList"
        data-dojo-props='uploaderId:"uploader"'></div> 
        <input type="submit" label="Submit" value="htmlsubmit" id="htmlsubmit">
        <input type="button" label="Submit" value="buttonsubmit" id="buttonsubmit" onclick="htmlsubmit.click();"/>
```

Comment: I need file data by executing document.forms[0].submit(), not by calling submit.

Comment: I cant understand... You try to send a file to database? Or Upload file?